# How do you move an ImageButton without compressing the image?

Tags: android, xml

As you can [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1epDE.jpg), my calendar image is roughly equal on both sides of the white layout, which is what I want, however the image was compressed/shrunk when I added 'paddingLeft'. How could I move the image to the right without shrinking it horizontally to fit?

Here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftTopLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:translationX="2dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/calendar"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, when I change the 'paddingLeft' to 'layout_marginLeft', it does the exact same thing, it compressed the image horizontally rather than shifting it to the right.

Comment: try scale type `CENTER_INSIDE` ? it is supposed to retain the aspect ration `fitXY`  can change the aspect ration

Comment: That did the exact same thing as fitXY, compressed it horizontally.

Comment: strange  `android:scaleType="centerInside"` prevents the distortion of aspect ratio for me

Comment: I think it did as you intended actually, it still is off centre, which is the issue I was trying to fix but it is actually scaled correctly.